# Slow query execution on big table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

My query takes about 1.8s. Is there any way how to optimize this query?

This is the execution plan:

[image: execution plan]

The query:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE("SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."DAT",  "LPA_P1"."Datum") AS "Dat",
       COALESCE("SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."OS_C", "LPA_P1"."MfKpracOsC") AS "OsC",
       COALESCE("SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."HOD_VYKON", 0 /* :p2 */ ) AS "HodVykon",
       COALESCE("LPA_P1"."PlCas",    0 /* :p4 */ ) AS "SumarZaDen",
       "LPA_P1"."Id" AS "PlId",
       "SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."PKH" AS "MajstId",
       "SMTAPP"."MF_KPRAC"."MENO" AS "Meno",
       "SMTAPP"."MF_KPRAC"."PRIEZVISKO" AS "Priezvisko",
       "SMTAPP"."MF_KPRAC"."OZ" AS "Oz"
FROM
(
  (
    (
      SELECT SUM(COALESCE("LPA_C2"."Cas", 0 /* :p6 */)) AS "PlCas",
             "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."MF_KPRAC_OS_C" AS "MfKpracOsC",
             "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."DATUM" AS "Datum",
             "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."ID" AS "Id"
      FROM
      (
        (
          SELECT "SMTAPP"."MP_PRACOVNY_LIST_HODINY"."CAS" AS "Cas",
                 "SMTAPP"."MP_PRACOVNY_LIST_HODINY"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST_ID" AS "MfPracovnyListId"
          FROM
          (
            "SMTAPP"."MP_PRACOVNY_LIST_HODINY"
            LEFT JOIN "SMTAPP"."MC_PRACOVNY_LIST_TYP"
            ON        "SMTAPP"."MC_PRACOVNY_LIST_TYP"."ID" = "SMTAPP"."MP_PRACOVNY_LIST_HODINY"."MC_PRACOVNY_LIST_TYP_ID"
          )
          WHERE
          (
            (
              (
              "SMTAPP"."MC_PRACOVNY_LIST_TYP"."POCITAT_DO_ODPRAC_HODIN" = 1 /* :p7 */
              )
            )
          )
        ) "LPA_C2"
        RIGHT JOIN "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"
        ON "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."ID" = "LPA_C2"."MfPracovnyListId"
      )
      GROUP BY "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."MF_KPRAC_OS_C",
               "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."DATUM",
               "SMTAPP"."MF_PRACOVNY_LIST"."ID"
    ) "LPA_P1" FULL
    JOIN "SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"
    ON
    (
          "LPA_P1"."MfKpracOsC" = "SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."OS_C"
      AND "LPA_P1"."Datum" = "SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."DAT"
    )
  )
  LEFT JOIN "SMTAPP"."MF_KPRAC"
  ON "SMTAPP"."MF_KPRAC"."OS_C" = COALESCE("SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."OS_C", "LPA_P1"."MfKpracOsC")
)
WHERE
(
  (
    (
      COALESCE("SMTAPP"."MF_MAJST"."HOD_VYKON", 0 /* :p14 */) <> COALESCE("LPA_P1"."PlCas", 0 /* :p12 */)
    )
  )
)
AND rownum <= 15
```

Comment: Try using `full join` if that is what you want.

Comment: Why are you double quoting all the identifiers? You don't need to. Similar for all the repeated brackets; most of the time you need only one (and sometimes zero) brackets.

Comment: 1.8 seconds to query a million row table doesn't seem too shabby. How fast do you want it go?

Comment: @MT0 - unfortunately they do need to double-quote some of the identifiers: `"LPA_P1"."MfKpracOsC"` for instance. But in general I agree that this query is written in a way which makes it highly unreadable..

Comment: @APC `"LPA_P1"."MfKpracOsC"` is an alias created in one of the sub-queries. It could be unquoted in both locations and, as such, the quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: @mt0 - ah yes, so it is. What a horribly written query.

Comment: It is an ORM generated query.

Comment: To help tune the query, we need the runtime stats. You can get these by running `set serveroutput off

select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */<your query>...

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));`